# In a column of numbers, find the closest value to some target value

Tags: bash, awk

Let's say I have some numerical data in columns, something like

```
11.100000 36.829657 6.101642
11.400000 36.402069 5.731998
11.700000 35.953025 5.372652
12.000000 35.482082 5.023737
12.300000 34.988528 4.685519
12.600000 34.471490 4.358360
12.900000 33.930061 4.042693
13.200000 33.363428 3.738985
13.500000 32.770990 3.447709
13.800000 32.152473 3.169312
```

I also have a single target value and a column index. Given this set of data, I want to find the closest value to the target value in the column with the specified index.

For example, If my target value is `11.6` in column `1`, then the script should output `11.7`. If there are two numbers equidistant from the target value, then the higher value should be output.

I have a feeling that awk has the necessary functionality to do this, but any solution that works in a bash script is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
awk -v c=2 -v t=35 'NR==1{d=$c-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v=$c;next}{m=$c-t;m=m<0?-m:m}m<d{d=m;v=$c}END{print v}' file
```

the `-v c=2` and `-v t=35` could be dynamic value. they are the column idx (`c`) and your target value (`t`). in the above line, the parameter is  column 2 and target 25. They could be shell variable.

the output of above line based on given input data is:

```
kent$  awk -v c=2 -v t=35 'NR==1{d=$c-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v=$c;next}{m=$c-t;m=m<0?-m:m}m<d{d=m;v=$c}END{print v}' f
34.988528

kent$  awk -v c=1 -v t=11.6 'NR==1{d=$c-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v=$c;next}{m=$c-t;m=m<0?-m:m}m<d{d=m;v=$c}END{print v}' f
11.700000
```

**EDIT**

> If there are two numbers equidistant from the target value, then the higher value should be output

The above codes didn't check this requirement.... the below one should work:

```
awk -v c=1 -v t=11.6 '{a[NR]=$c}END{
        asort(a);d=a[NR]-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v = a[NR]
        for(i=NR-1;i>=1;i--){
                m=a[i]-t;m=m<0?-m:m
                if(m<d){
                    d=m;v=a[i]
                }
        }
        print v
}' file
```

test:

```
kent$  awk -v c=1 -v t=11.6 '{a[NR]=$c}END{
        asort(a);d=a[NR]-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v = a[NR]
        for(i=NR-1;i>=1;i--){
                m=a[i]-t;m=m<0?-m:m
                if(m<d){
                    d=m;v=a[i]
                }
        }
        print v
}' f
11.700000
```

short explanation.

I won't explain each line of code, what it does. just tell a bit the idea to do the job.

- first read all element in the given column, save in an array
- sort the array.
- take the last element from the array(the greatest number). assign it to var `v`, and calculate the diff between it and the given target, save it(absolute value) in `d`
- from the 2nd last element from the array loop to the first. if diff between element and target (absolute value) is less than `d`, overwrite `d` with diff, also save current element into `v`
- print v, after looping, v  is the answer.

**some note**:

- there is room to optimize the logic. e.g. we don't have to loop thru the whole array. just compare the `d(abs)`, if new diff > d, we can stop the loop.
- due to the sort, this algorithm is **`O(nlogn)`**. in fact this problem could be solved by **`O(n)`**. If your input data were huge, and with a worst case(e.g. your column has value in range `500-99999999999`, but your target is 1.) you may want to avoid the sort. but I assume the performance is not an issue by you.

Comment: **+1** Good work, I tip my hat to you Kent ;)  `awk` on macOS lacks the built-in `asort()` function, so I just had to omit that part and sort the input data prior to usage. This came in very handy for finding file(s) with a birth time (i.e. created date) closest to a given epoch time.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try another way, although Kent's answer must be shorter and sharper :)

```
awk -vc=1 -vv=13.6 '
    BEGIN{l=$c; ld=99}
    {d=($c-v>=0) ? ($c-v) : v-$c; if (d <= ld) {ld=d; l=$c}}
    END{print l}' file
```

We provide the `c` (=column) and `v` (=value) parameters in the beginning.

Then we keep track of the lower value `l` and the lowest distance `ld`. For each value we calculate the distance `d` to the value and if it is lower to the previous `ld`, we swap and save the new minimal value in `l`. Finally we print `l`.

The `d=($c-v>=0) ? ($c-v) : v-$c` is a way to save the distance as a absolute value: if `c-v` is negative, save it as positive. It is based on the `value=(condition) ? if yes : else` structure.

#### Tests

```
$ awk -vc=2 -vv=13.6 'BEGIN{l=$c; ld=99} {d=($c-v>=0) ? ($c-v) : v-$c; if (d <= ld) {ld=d; l=$c}} END{print l}' file
32.152473
$ awk -vc=3 -vv=10.6 'BEGIN{l=$c; ld=99} {d=($c-v>=0) ? ($c-v) : v-$c; if (d <= ld) {ld=d; l=$c}} END{print l}' file
3.169312
```

Comment: I guess there could be some small problem in your logic... since if you test `c=2 v=35`, I got `35.482...`, but I think the `34.988528` would be the answer. because 0.482.. > 0.114..`  I didn't read your so carefully, but why you do a `v-$1`? it would be `v-$c` right? typo?  and the magic number `99` is not safe for all cases. Also the `equidistant` case wasn't checked. I neglected it too before I edit my answer.

Comment: Oh yes, it was a typo @Kent. As I started checking the col 1 case, I forgot updating. I checked the `equidistant` case, and should work with `d <= ld` condition but it does not, uhms... And thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

@ARGV == 2 or die "Usage: closest column value < input\n";
my ($column, $target) = (shift, shift);
my $closest;
while (<>) {
    my $value = (split)[$column - 1];
    if ($. == 1
        or abs($closest - $target) >  abs($target - $value)
        or abs($closest - $target) == abs($target - $value)
           && $value > $closest) {
        $closest = $value;
    }
}
print $closest, "\n";
```

Note that using *float == float* might not work ([What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floatin-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)). You might need something like `abs(abs($closest - $target) - abs($target - $value)) < 1e-14`.