# How to get row details corresponding to a value (real number) which is closer to the user specified number in Linux scripting

Tags: linux, shell

This is regarding Linux scripting. I have a text file as shown below. It has three columns c1, c2 and c3

```
c1      c2      c3
151.2   **a**   120
151.6   **b**   130
152.1   **c**   140
152.3   **d**   150
152.6   **e**   160
```

I would like to get the row corresponding to value `152.0` in first column(`c1`) of the file. As exact `152.0` is not there, row corresponding to a number close to `152.0` (in this case `152.1`) has to be extracted. The row number for `152.0` may not be same for all the files from which I need to extract the data.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853037/in-a-column-of-numbers-find-the-closest-value-to-some-target-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a column of numbers, find the closest value to some target value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853037/in-a-column-of-numbers-find-the-closest-value-to-some-target-value)